# Swing passing a @State var as argument does not update view

Tags: swift, animation, parameter-passing, state

I am following the Apple Developer Tutorial for SwingUI and I am pretty new. I am working on animations currently and I am confused about `@State` variables. Let's look at the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HikeDetail: View {
    let hike: Hike
    @State var dataToShow = \Hike.Observation.elevation
    
    var buttons = [
        ("Elevation", \Hike.Observation.elevation),
        ("Heart Rate", \Hike.Observation.heartRate),
        ("Pace", \Hike.Observation.pace),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HikeGraph(hike: hike, path: self.dataToShow)
                .frame(height: 200)
            
            HStack(spacing: 25) {
                ForEach(buttons, id: \.0) { value in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.dataToShow = value.1
                    }) {
                        Text(value.0)
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(value.1 == self.dataToShow
                                ? Color.green
                                : Color.accentColor)
                            .animation(nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HikeGraph** is another SwiftUI View that produces a graph, it has three options:

```
- elevation => gray color
- heartRate  => red color
- pace    => purple color
```

Each of them has a different color and shape, however when I change between these three options, I only see one type of graph which is the initially defined one.

```
    @State var dataToShow = \Hike.Observation.elevation
```

When I change the path variable of:

```
    HikeGraph(hike: hike, path: dataToShow)
        .frame(height: 200)
```

The graph does not change. However, when I change `dataToShow` variable by myself, I can observe the color change.

My question is how can I update the graph itself when the state variable is changed.

Edit: HikeGraph View

```
import SwiftUI

func rangeOfRanges<C: Collection>(_ ranges: C) -> Range<Double>
    where C.Element == Range<Double> {
    guard !ranges.isEmpty else { return 0..<0 }
    let low = ranges.lazy.map { $0.lowerBound }.min()!
    let high = ranges.lazy.map { $0.upperBound }.max()!
    return low..<high
}

func magnitude(of range: Range<Double>) -> Double {
    return range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
}

extension Animation {
    static func ripple(index: Int) -> Animation {
        Animation.spring(dampingFraction: 0.5)
            .speed(2)
            .delay(0.03 * Double(index))
    }
}

struct HikeGraph: View {
    var hike: Hike
    var path: KeyPath<Hike.Observation, Range<Double>>
    
    var color: Color {
        switch path {
        case \.elevation:
            return .gray
        case \.heartRate:
            return Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.7)
        case \.pace:
            return Color(hue: 0.7, saturation: 0.4, brightness: 0.7)
        default:
            return .black
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let data = hike.observations
        let overallRange = rangeOfRanges(data.lazy.map { $0[keyPath: self.path] })
        let maxMagnitude = data.map { magnitude(of: $0[keyPath: path]) }.max()!
        let heightRatio = (1 - CGFloat(maxMagnitude / magnitude(of: overallRange))) / 2

        return GeometryReader { proxy in
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: proxy.size.width / 120) {
                ForEach(data.indices) { index in
                    GraphCapsule(
                        index: index,
                        height: proxy.size.height,
                        range: data[index][keyPath: self.path],
                        overallRange: overallRange)
                    .colorMultiply(self.color)
                    .transition(.slide)
                    .animation(.ripple(index: index))
                }
                .offset(x: 0, y: proxy.size.height * heightRatio)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `change dataToShow variable by myself`, manually in arguments?

Comment: @Asperi  Changing its initial value from `.elevation` to `.pace` or `.heartRate`

Comment: As far as I made simple working replication from your code `@State` for key paths works fine, so it is something inside `HikeGraph`

Comment: Can you show the HikeGraph View? Did you use the @Binding property wrapper in your HikeGraph?

Comment: @SebastianFox I did not actually, I am adding